# Trigger addError('blah') -> Lightning Components JS alert('contense of addError('blah')')

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, before-trigger, adderror

I am sure my Title does not help much, but not sure how to shorten this question concisely.

I have a Lightning Component that has the ability to update a case record. I have an APEX Trigger that under some rarer conditions will stop that update from happening.

How can I show the `thisCase.addError('Blah blah blah')` from the Trigger on the Lightning Component? Do I have to `try` and `catch` the update statement in my APEX Lightning Controller? I would not think so as I don't see in messages coming through the Dev Console without the Try Catch block.

Editing the Case record directly shows the `addError()` as expected. Just wondering how to transfer the contents of the `addError()` to the Lightning Component for display as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are invoking the update on your record from Apex Controller, you will need to catch the `DMLException` and then propagate the exception to your Lightning Aura Component using `AuraHandledException`.

The code in your apex controller will look something as:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String myCaseUpdate(Case c) { 
    ...
    try {
        update c;
    } catch (DMLException dml) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('your exception message');
    }
    ...
}
```

You can find more details on [Returning Errors from an Apex Server-Side Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm)

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much @Jayant !

Comment: @DanielW Happy to help. Glad that it worked for you :)